# how to capture the click outside the input text field area in html & angular js

Tags: angularjs

The dropdown has some values to select, but `ng-blur` is not allowing me to select the value - it is clearing the text box.
I need to know the directive (`ng-`) to capture the click outside the html text box only.

---

Here what is happening is if u type & search something in the dropdown & try to select at that time ng-blur is clearing the result , so i cant select the results , i have handled this using the existing code , "i need to use ng-blur only for outside click of the whole control " below is the code :--->

HTML:

```
 ng-blur="clearsearchText()"
```

js:

```
 $scope.clearsearchText = function () {
     scope.typeahead.selected = "";
 }
```

Comment: `ng-blur` **is** the directive for that purpose. Can you show the code of how you are using it?

Comment: Here what is happening is if u type & search something in the dropdown & try to select at that time ng-blur is clearing the result , so i cant select the results , i have handled this using the existing code , "i need to use ng-blur only for outside click of the whole control "
          below is the code :--->                                                                                                            HTML: ng-blur="clearsearchText()".                                                                
      js:$scope.clearsearchText = function () { scope.typeahead.selected = "";}

Comment: thats a textbox and dropdown as well , if i type something & click outside ng-blur is clearing the thing that is fine , but if i select the value in the dropdown search result at that time value should not be cleared this is what i required

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are describing a solution, whereas you need to describe a problem. Where are you clicking "outside"? If it's a modal, it has a Promise that can be resolved with a rejection. You would be able to reset your form there. Is that the problem? `ng-blur` is not needed in this case

Comment: Correcting the above comment : thats a textbox and dropdown as well , if i type something & click outside ng-blur is clearing the thing that is fine , but if i select the value in the dropdown search result at that time value is getting cleared that is the problem                                                                                                2)this is not modal , it a separate page

Comment: depends on how you implement it. Here is [an example](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/UknxOoZNK1oDdhSN) with `ng-blur` that allows a proper selection

Comment: It’s really hard to answer a question about a bug in code when the question *doesn’t include any of the buggy code.* In order to help fix the problem, answerers are going to have to see what the code is.